# How to assign gameobject variables in inspector on a prefab that is initiated on a start of a game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scrip that control pick up and drop of a weapon but it requires some gameobject to be assigned to it to work but all my weapons are spawned on a game start since I'm using procedurally generated map (DunGen asset).
How can I assign them?

My code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponsPickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public BoxCollider coll;
    public Transform player, gunContainer, fpsCam;

    public float pickUpRange;
    public float dropForwardForce, dropUpwardForce;

    public bool equipped;
    public static bool slotFull;

    private void Start()
    {
        //Setup
        if (!equipped)
        {
            rb.isKinematic = false;
            coll.isTrigger = false;
        }
        if (equipped)
        {
            rb.isKinematic = true;
            coll.isTrigger = true;
            slotFull = true;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Check if player is in range and "E" is pressed
        Vector3 distanceToPlayer = player.position - transform.position;
        if (!equipped && distanceToPlayer.magnitude <= pickUpRange && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && !slotFull) PickUp();

        //Drop if equipped and "Q" is pressed
        if (equipped && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)) Drop();
    }

    private void PickUp()
    {
        equipped = true;
        slotFull = true;

        //Make weapon a child of the camera and move it to default position
        transform.SetParent(gunContainer);
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero);
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        //Make Rigidbody kinematic and BoxCollider a trigger
        rb.isKinematic = true;
        coll.isTrigger = true;
    }

    private void Drop()
    {
        equipped = false;
        slotFull = false;

        //Set parent to null
        transform.SetParent(null);

        //Make Rigidbody not kinematic and BoxCollider normal
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        coll.isTrigger = false;

        //Gun carries momentum of player
        rb.velocity = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;

        //AddForce
        rb.AddForce(fpsCam.forward * dropForwardForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        rb.AddForce(fpsCam.up * dropUpwardForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        //Add random rotation
        float random = Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
        rb.AddTorque(new Vector3(random, random, random) * 10);
    }
}
```

[I want to add gameobjects to these variables but I cant until i place them into a scene but they are spawned at start of a game.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWySd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assign the tag of the object weapon (or whatever object you are needing to script), then something like:

```
public Transform _weapon;

void Start() {
     _weapon = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("weapon").GetComponent<_weapon>();
}
```

should work for you.

Comment: should work, but isn't really efficient. When instantiating the objects, you get a reference that you can assign, avoiding the `Find...` call.

Comment: Yes but his problem is that he want to assign them during runtime ... but if you know a more effient method then I would love to know it!

Comment: I know, but again: OP spawns weapons during game's start. He should assign them directly after spawning them, because `FindGameObjectWithTag` won't work **before** they are spawned. So why not use the reference that `Instantiate` returns? :P But that spawn-code is missing so I can't suggest something concrete.

Comment: Not quite what i needed i need to add component from a another gameobjects.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean ... hmm, perhaps we need an event or something of the like to notify us of when they have been instantiated. It seems the instantiate call must be in another scrpit?

Comment: They are always instantiated at a start of a game

Comment: I accidentally put Awake() function in Start() function instead under it now I fixed it and now it works fine thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a **TAG** to your gameObject to spawn and the work is done.

For example if you have a tag "enemy" on your enemy that needs to spawn you can use the tag instead of public variables like that.

```
GameObject enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("enemy");
```

And then of course access to the components like that

```
Rigidbody rb = enemy.getComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

With this you are also able to decide when you find that object because if there is no object with tag "enemy" it will simply not assign `GameObject enemy` and it will be **null** until one spawns (if you put it in the Update())